# Generic Methods for async await in a class Library

Tags: c#, async-await, class-library

Is it possible to write generic async methods in a Dot Net 4.0 class Library?

**Reason for asking this**
Because then I will be able to use this dll in any project that targets .Net 4.0. Even use in IDE's like VS 2010 which do not support await and async keywords.

**Problem**
My problem is that my main app code is in .Net 4.0 and I use VS 2010. I was thinking that I will use VS 2012 to create a generic dll which I can reference in my main code and use it.

In my app there are some code that takes time and is fires in UI Thread, causing my app to hang. If I can achieve what I want, then those synchronous calls will not hang UI.

Something like this

```
public static class AsyncHelpers
{
    public static async Task<T> RunMethodAsync<T>()
    {
        //What to do here?
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not relying on a different multithreading approach? `await` and `async` are just one of the possible options, not everything. For example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e8s7xdd(v=vs.85).aspx.

Comment: Google "Async Targeting Pack". `await` is in the compiler, not the runtime, so it works with 4.0 just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use async/await in a project that targets .NET 4.0; you just need to reference the [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/) NuGet package, which provides the necessary types. And of course you also need the C# 5 (or higher) compiler, which means VS2012 or more recent.

Answer (score 0):

I did it. Here's what I did.

If you use .Net 4.0 using Nuget Package Manager Console, install [Microsoft BCL Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/). Then use this code

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AsyncAwaitCL
{
    public class AsyncHelpers
    {
        public static async Task<T> RunMethodAsync<T>(Task<T> task)
        {
            T returnValue = default(T);
            returnValue = await task;
            return returnValue;
        }
    }
}
```

and you are done.

Comment: I'm with @ThomasLevesque on this one: not only does this method not accomplish anything useful, it introduces the (potentially harmful) `SynchronizationContext` capture behaviour (`await` without `ConfigureAwait(false)`), making the resulting task prone to deadlocking even if the original task wasn't.